# Random generation of ipv6 address in perl

Tags: perl, ipv6

I have to **randomly generate IPV6** address using Perl.

Please help me.

Comment: Show some code, and you might get some help fixing it. SO is not a code writing service, you have to do that.

Comment: if you want someone to write the code for you then you would have to pay them, if you have some code thats not working and you need help with it then this is the place, but you have to show some effort to have coded a solution and some research and understanding into the problem and what your failing on.

Comment: What kind of output do you want? Actually ip address is a sequence of bytes. Do you want to get 16 random bytes?)

Comment: If this is for IPv6 Privacy Extensions, [RFC 4941,Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4941#section-3.2), suggests using [RFC 1750, Randomness Recommendations for Security](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1750), which has algorithms for randomness.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear whether you want just *any* 128-bit pattern, or if you need to skip [*reserved IP addresses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv6)

This program solves the most basic interpretation

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $ipv6 = join ':', map { sprintf '%04X', rand 0x10000 } 1 .. 8;

say $ipv6;
```

#### output example

```
FDFE:5E91:137C:8482:DCB2:03D9:2C1D:8A75
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string that contains some ipv6-address, you can use this code:

```
my $addr_str = '';
$addr_str .= (($_) ? ':' : '') . sprintf "%04x", rand 0xFFFF + 1 for 0..7; 
# $addr_str =~ s/0000//g; # to reduce when zero-block appears
```

Comment: There's no need to get a random number for every four-bit nybble, and the double-colon is incorrect in this case as it stands for *at least one* all-zero 16-bit block

Comment: Of course you are right @Borodin. I edited my post not to confuse anyone with unnecessary loop. It's interesting, that now my code works a little bit faster than your. Through the some tests on `Benchmark`.  The `map` is to blame?

Comment: I don't want to encourage you to do benchmarks; preemptive tuning is a legacy burden from when we were programming Z80 assembler and *knew* that our code would be too slow if it wasn't optmised. C21 hardware and compiler technology allows us to mostly ignore tuning. Firstly, the *clarity* of the code you write is paramount: shaving just a few seconds off the time it takes anyone to understand your code can amount to a huge saving that will easily buy a faster computer with more cores that puts any optimisation in the shade.

Comment: Secondly, if you are writing a real-time application with a user interface then you will have to make your code run *twice as fast* before the user notices a significant improvement. It is only if you have to work within system margins for processor, memory, and storage that you should even consider doing any tuning at all, and then you should use profiling to determine where the bottlenecks are in your code.